# how to background color a button on basis of percentage

Tags: android, button, background-color, percentage

I want to change the background color of a button on basis of percentage.

I am getting 20% as a input-It should show the background color of a button which is filled by some color let's say green only 20% green.

20% I mean that Button should fill only 20% width of its 100%. So It look like Seekbar. but actually it will be button.

40% input -So only 40% background color is filled with green color  and so on.

Any idea how to do so?

Note : **Please don't tell to use Seekbar or Progressbar.**

Comment: What is purpose to use only button? I can give you option with use of seekbar and button to gether

Comment: I have a custom button which is of exact UI requirement

Comment: you can do it by designing  custom view

Comment: Restate your question please.

Comment: For batter explanation you can put some image like if i input 20% button have 20% green and 80%white like graphical view need to draw on paper

Comment: Do you want that, if user input 20%, considering whole button width as 100%, only bottom 20% out of 100% width should be green colored rest to be default button color , if input 40% only 40% out of 100% width should be green colored?

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela yes exactly

Answer (score 4):

With Button I am seeing any way to do that. But the same I done Previously.

So May be this will help you.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relProgress"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#d7d7d7"
        android:clickable="true"
         >
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressDownload"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_style" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/txtProgressDownload"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="30%"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="#4d5359"
            android:textSize="15dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**progressbar_style.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>



        <solid android:color="#ccd4e0" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>

            <solid android:color="#6dd451" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Set **Progressbar Progress programmatically**

```
progressDownload.setProgress(20);
```

Comment: i said clearly , i don't have tio use Progressbar

Comment: This will serve same purpose. Without that I am not seeing its possible. Thank you.

Comment: I have to set it grammatically , so that any input percentage can set to the a bckground color of a button

Comment: You can set percentage to programmatically  to seekbar. and button color is transparent so it will look like button is filled with color. Serve the same purpose

Comment: SID is right you can set the progress programmatically

Comment: @abh22ishek See updated Answer

Comment: @SID . I appreciate your inputs , but the real reason i don't want to use progressbar beacuse in real case my custom button is round , and could be any other way, so if i use progressbar , how will i fill the color in it. ? and there should be no progress style horizontal, imay have to fill the color vertical in circular button

Comment: you can give radius to the shape too and progressbar will be circular. and about fill vertical I need to research.

Answer (score 1):

Here is My solution with cutom view

```
public class PrecentageButton extends View {

    private Paint paintDefault;
    private Paint paintFilled;
    private RectF rectDefault;
    private RectF rectFilled;
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;
    private float precentValue=20;

    public PrecentageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        paintDefault = new Paint();
        paintDefault.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        paintFilled = new Paint();
        paintFilled.setColor(Color.GREEN);


        rectDefault = new RectF();
        rectFilled = new RectF();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        mWidth = getWidth();
        mHeight = getHeight();


        rectDefault.set(10, 10, 200, 100);
        rectFilled.set(10, 10, precentValue, 100);

        canvas.drawRect(rectDefault, paintDefault);
        canvas.drawRect(rectFilled, paintFilled);


    }

    public void setPrecentValue(int precentValue) {
        this.precentValue = precentValue;
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

**OUTUPT**

[image]